# MySQL - Count() and multiply result by 400

Tags: mysql, database, count

just a quick and easy question, nothing too complicated.
I'm making a function in MySQL that returns total revenue from a specific flight and my question is this; can I COUNT() WHERE the values of paymentType = 1, and then multiply them by the price of a flight ticket? I did try this, but it didn't multiply for some reason. 
Example of what I'm thinking:

```
SELECT COUNT(paymentType * 400) FROM booking
WHERE paymentType = 1;
```

Here is the code between begin and end$$.

```
DECLARE revenue INT;

SELECT COUNT(paymentType) INTO revenue FROM booking
INNER JOIN flights
ON booking.flightCode = flights.flightCode
WHERE paymentType = 1
AND flights.flightDate = flight_date
AND flights.flightNumber = flight_number;

RETURN revenue;
```

Comment: Try `SELECT COUNT(paymentType) * 400 FROM booking`

Comment: I'm an idiot and you are helpful, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`count()` just checks if the specified field is non-null, and counts that as `1`, regardless of the value in there. `count(somefield*400)` and `count(somefield)` will basically all give the exact same count

If you want to multiple the count ITSELF by 400, then you'd need

```
select count(somefield) * 400 as result
```